# CSS display issues with github pages

Tags: css, github-pages

Having trouble displaying my css on github pages. Everything works when ran in default browser (as seen in image) however when I published to pages it fails to load with the css. I have tried changing the href tag but not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point after a couple attempts at changing around the link.

Link to Repo: https://github.com/trentstanley92/02ProfessionalPortfolio
Link to Pages: https://trentstanley92.github.io/02ProfessionalPortfolio/

[Default browser css loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nym21.png)

I have tried changing the href link to 02ProfessionalPortfolio/Assets/styles.css tag a couple times. Ultimately the one linked above is my final attempt after starting at link rel="stylesheet" href="=./Assets/styles.css". I expected the second line to pull up the css on its own, however after it didnt I messed around with the capitalization and the ./ at the beginning and when those did not work I resulted to the first and final attempt, which did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your web browser's Developer tools.

Your page is trying to load this:
https://trentstanley92.github.io/02ProfessionalPortfolio/02ProfessionalPortfolio/Assets/styles.css

But the file lives here:
https://trentstanley92.github.io/02ProfessionalPortfolio/Assets/styles.css

Your `index.html` is already at `02ProfessionalPortfolio`, so you just need to write it as follows to hit the relative address:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/styles.css" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I suppose it was taking way longer than expected to load the results.

Comment: Try it again. And use your Developer Tools' network tab to see what URLs it's hitting.

Comment: And the reason your images aren't loading is because your HTML references `assets` but the actual URL uses `Assets` (capitalized).

Comment: Its working now but just as a question my original link which didn't work was "./Assets/styles.css" what would be the difference between that and the "Assets/styles.css"

Comment: It should have worked without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are already in 02ProfessionalPortfolio, you can change the href in the  element to "Assets/styles.css".

Comment: Hi, this was ultimately how I had it when i first uploaded to pages and still no css displaying.

Comment: yes it just took way longer to load and a lot of refreshes lol. Thank you